# How to create swap partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, memory

I think every laptop has swap partition by default I had no idea of it. While I was doing some searches in Google I notice that it is related to ram.

> The primary function of swap space is to substitute disk space for RAM memory when real RAM fills up and more space is needed. For example, assume you have a computer system with 8GB of RAM.

Mistakenly I removed the swap partition. So, I want to create the partition again how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think every laptop has swap partition by default

This isn't entirely accurate – although most operating systems indeed use some sort of swap/paging area, not all of them use a *partition*. For example, Windows instead uses a file (named "pagefile.sys"). Linux systems can use either a file or a partition.

> Mistakenly I removed the swap partition. So, I want to set up the partition again how to do that?

Create an empty partition. Format it using `mkswap`. Add the partition to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: How many storage(minimum) do I need for swap partition?